# where the files goes when restore that file in trash

Tags: delete, restore, trash

Accidentally one of my folder was delete by my own self(That folder was at `Downloads`). And then I moved to `trash` and that folder was there. Then I right click on that folder and select `restore`. But now that folder is not in `Downloads` neither `trash` ,So where that file goes after `restore` ? Is there any way to get that file ?

(I'm using `ubuntu 12.04`)

In terminal I tried this to search it as said in [early question asked in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95403/i-can-not-recover-files-from-trash) `cd .local/share/Trash/file`s but after `ls` that was empty . Give some help.

Comment: Just tried this in my 12.04.3LTS64bit (Dutch): Restore works flawlessly both on empty and populated subfolders. Can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on terminal,

```
find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "foldername"
```

Comment: What would this command do?

Comment: This command search for the folder and display its path.

Comment: @Avinash Raj-I did what you said here.It takes some time, but shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my Downloads folder, and then attempted to restore from trash, and it restored to the original location by default.

Also deleted a folder from inside the Downloads folder, and it also was restored to the original location.

To find where the folder is on the drive, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
find / -type d -name "folder_name" 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: But to me its not

Comment: See my addition in my answer on how to locate.

Comment: -I did what you said here.It takes some time, but shows nothing.

Comment: Then, I hate to tell you that the file was permanently deleted.  Try using [formost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/).