# Deleted everything in Jupyter, cannot recover files from Trash

Tags: data-recovery, delete, trash, jupyter

I promise I already searched for this!

The problem I am facing is that I deleted all of my directories, or at least all of the ones that showed up in Jupyter Notebook. Why, you ask? Because I am a fool.

TL;DR:

I think the crux of the matter is that /Desktop is not a recognized directory anymore. However, I also cannot create this directory. It is stuck in limbo.

Here is some code from terminal:

```
paul@Paul:~$ cd Desktop
bash: cd: Desktop: Not a directory
paul@Paul:~$ mkdir Desktop
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Desktop’: File exists
```

MORE INFO:

As mentioned, I deleted everything that was showing up in my Notebook. My desktop is now devoid of all files, which have been relocated to Trash. However, when I try to recover them, Files fails to respond. It just freezes up. Now, Ubuntu both recognizes /Desktop as a file that exists, and also that it is not a directory. I had hoped that [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95403/i-can-not-recover-files-from-trash) would work, but since my system does not recognize /Desktop (I *think* this is the reason) it doesn't work.

I'm just looking to restore these files. I an see them in the Trash just fine, but I cannot get them back out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome top askubuntu! Have you considered simply copying and pasting the files from the trash to a thumb drive in order to recover them? You might find this Q & A useful. https://askubuntu.com/questions/102099/where-is-the-trash-folder

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ...

```
paul@Paul:~$ cd Desktop
bash: cd: Desktop: Not a directory
paul@Paul:~$ mkdir Desktop
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Desktop’: File exists
```

That means Desktop exists and is not a directory... so it is a file (like the last line tell you ;))

Do

```
ls -l Desktop
```

If it is a file checks its contents. If empty(!)

```
rm Desktop
```

After that go to the trash directory and check it contents; then find the place it should belong and use `cp -R` with the files and destination to copy them back.